# Swift: unexpected behavior when setting DateComponents year

Tags: swift, date, swift3, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

The example code below gets DateComponents from the current Date, modifies the components, and creates a new Date from the modified components. It also shows creating a new DateComponents object, filling it out, and then creating a new Date from that.

```
import Foundation

let utcHourOffset = -7.0
let tz = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: Int(utcHourOffset*60.0*60.0))!
let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
var now = calendar.dateComponents(in: tz, from: Date())

// Get and display current date
print("\nCurrent Date:")
print("\(now.month!)/\(now.day!)/\(now.year!) \(now.hour!):\(now.minute!):\(now.second!)   \(now.timeZone!)")
let curDate = calendar.date(from: now)
print("\(curDate!)")

// Modify and display current date
now.year = 2010
now.month = 2
now.day = 24
now.minute = 0
print("\nModified Date:")
print("\(now.month!)/\(now.day!)/\(now.year!) \(now.hour!):\(now.minute!):\(now.second!)   \(now.timeZone!)")
let modDate = calendar.date(from: now)
print("\(modDate!)")

// Create completely new date
var dc = DateComponents()
dc.year = 2014
dc.month = 12
dc.day = 25
dc.hour = 10
dc.minute = 12
dc.second = 34
print("\nNew Date:")
print("\(dc.month!)/\(dc.day!)/\(dc.year!) \(dc.hour!):\(dc.minute!):\(dc.second!)   \(now.timeZone!)")
let newDate = calendar.date(from: dc)
print("\(newDate!)")
```

In the case where I modify the components, setting different year, month, day, etc., then use the components to get a date, I get the unexpected result that the new date has all the modified components except the year, which remains unchanged.

In the case where I create a DateComponents object and fill it out then create a Date from it, it works as expected.

The output of the code is shown below:

```
Current Date:
3/9/2017 19:5:30   GMT-0700 (fixed)
2017-03-10 02:05:30 +0000

Modified Date:
2/24/2010 19:0:30   GMT-0700 (fixed)
2017-02-25 02:00:30 +0000

New Date:
12/25/2014 10:12:34   GMT-0700 (fixed)
2014-12-25 17:12:34 +0000
```

I expected the modified Date to be `2010-02-25 02:00:30 +0000` rather than `2017-02-25 02:00:30 +0000`. Why isn't it? Why does it work in the second case?

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdatecomponents) for DateComponents say: "An instance of NSDateComponents is not responsible for answering questions about a date beyond the information with which it was initialized...". Being that the DateComponents object was initialized with a year, it doesn't seem like this would apply, but it's the only thing I saw in the docs that might explain the behavior I observe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you log `now` and `dc` you will see the problem. `now` is being created from a `Date`. This fills in all of the date components including `yearForWeekOfYear` and several of the weekday related components. These components are causing `modDate` to come out incorrectly.

`newDate` works as expected because only the specific components are being set.

You can get `modDate` to come out correctly if you reset some of the extra components. Specifically, adding:

```
now.yearForWeekOfYear = nil
```

just before creating `modDate` will result in the expected date for `modDate`. Of course the best solution is to create a new instance of `DateComponents` and use specific values from the previous `DateComponents` as needed:

```
let mod = DateComponents()
mod.timeZone = now.timeZone
mod.year = 2010
mod.month = 2
mod.day = 24
mod.hour = now.hour
mod.minute = 0
mod.second = now.second
print("\nModified Date:")
print("\(mod.month!)/\(mod.day!)/\(mod.year!) \(mod.hour!):\(mod.minute!):\(mod.second!)   \(mod.timeZone!)")
let modDate = calendar.date(from: mod)
print("\(modDate!)")
```